# Asp.Net Core MVC don't load view

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application with ASP.NET core and I have encountered some issues.
I'm redirecting my application when I get to a controller, to another controller that opens a page. However, when I get to the controller that returns the view that should be opened, nothing happens and the page doesn't load. The request arrives at the controller which returns the view but the page does not open. The curious thing is that when creating a menu option for the page, everything works normally and the page is loaded.
The first controller is called by Ajax code, receives the information and then calls the other controller to open the other view. Could Ajax code be causing this problem?

Ajax Code

```js
<script>
        var listaDeIds = [];
        function Mostrar() {
            var videos = document.querySelectorAll('#video');
            var count = 0;
            var lista = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
                var videoID = videos.item(i).getAttribute("name");
                const shadow = videos.item(i).shadowRoot;
                const childNodes = Array.from(shadow.childNodes);

                childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
                    if (childNode.nodeName === "DIV") {
                        const shadowChilds = Array.from(childNode.childNodes);
                        shadowChilds.forEach(shadowShild => {
                            if (shadowShild.nodeName === "DIV") {
                                const shadowChildsInternas = Array.from(shadowShild.childNodes);
                                shadowChildsInternas.forEach(interna => {
                                    if (interna.nodeName === "INPUT") {
                                        if (interna.checked === true) {
                                            lista[count] = videoID;
                                            count = count + 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            if (lista.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("btnplaylist").style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById("btnplaylist").style.display = 'none';
            }
            listaDeIds = lista;
        }

        $('#Playlist').click(function () {
            //var url = "/Playlist/RecebeListaDeIds";
            var url = "/VideoSearch/PegarListaDeIds"
            var lista = listaDeIds;

            $.post(url, { pListaDeIds: lista }, function (data) {
                $("#msg").html(data);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Controller 1 that receives data from the screen and calls the other controller

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PegarListaDeIds(string[] pListaDeIds)
    {
      if(AppUser.User != null)
      {
        var appCache = AppCache.Instance;
        appCache.VideoId.InserirNoCache(pListaDeIds);

        return RedirectToAction("CreatePlaylist", "Playlist");
      }
      else
      {
        return BadRequest("Usuário não está logado");
      }
    }
```

Controller 2 which is called by controller 1. This controller when called by another controller does not load the View.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreatePlaylist()
    {
      return View();
    }
```

Comment: You have to submit form , ajax doesn' t allow to redirect from the action. If you want to redirect to another controller you have to put redirect code in ajax, not in the action.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I added this snippet to my Ajax code and now everything works fine.

```js
var url = '@Url.Action("CreatePlaylist", "Playlist")';
window.location.href = url.replace();
```